# Mobx Obervable Not Causing Observer Component To Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

**The Requirement** is:

> 1. when user changes input in DayView component, the number of shifts in that day instance is changed to the input value (i.e. 4 in input means day.shifts.length == 4)
> 2. when day.shifts changes, then DayView.renderShifts causes N rows to be rendered

However, changing the input value works but,the DayView.render is called only once. It should called again after day.shifts is changed.

What am I missing?

Here is my **observer components**:

```
//App.js
import React from 'react';
import store from './ShiftStore';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { toJS } from 'mobx';

@observer class ShiftList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { store.days.map(
          (day, idx) => <DayView day={ day } key={ idx } />
        ) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

@observer class DayView extends React.Component {
  renderShifts(day) {
    var rows = [];
    toJS(day.shifts).forEach(function(s) {
      rows.push(<div>Shift Row</div>)
    })
    return rows;
  }

  render() {
    const day = this.props.day;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="number"
          onChange={(e) => day.resizeShifts(e.target.value)}/>
        {this.renderShifts(day)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ShiftList/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here is the **mobx side**:

```
//ShiftStore.js
import React from 'react';
import {observable, computed, action, toJS } from 'mobx';

class Shift {
   @observable startTime = 10;
   @observable endTime = 9;
   @computed get duration() {
     let { startTime, endTime } = this;
     return endTime - startTime;
   }
}

class Day {
  @observable shifts = [];
  @action resizeShifts(n) {
    if (n < 0 || n % 1 !== 0) return;
    let { shifts, _resize } = this;
    let shiftArr = toJS(shifts);
    _resize(shiftArr, n, new Shift());
    shifts = shiftArr;
  }
  _resize(arr, newSize, defaultValue) {
      while(newSize > arr.length)
          arr.push(defaultValue);
      arr.length = newSize;
  }
}

class ShiftStore {
  constructor(props) {
    this.addDay = this.addDay.bind(this);
  }
  @observable days = [new Day()];
  addDay() { this.days.push(new Day()); }
}

const shiftStore = new ShiftStore();
export default shiftStore;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never assigning your `shifts` a new array. Use [**replace**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html) so you don't overwrite the reference to your observable array:

```
@action resizeShifts(n) {
  if (n < 0 || n % 1 !== 0) return;
  let { shifts, _resize } = this;
  let shiftArr = toJS(shifts);
  _resize(shiftArr, n, new Shift());
  this.shifts.replace(shiftArr);
}
```

Comment: @JackRobson Great! Glad I could help.